# Bad Request - Invalid URL HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid. while using SSL on domain name and JWT token inside NodeJS

Tags: node.js, windows, api, iis, server

My URL is not working while fetching the data from Server. What I have done is as follows:

> - Created the Node JS application using Bcrypt and JWT tokens in IIS server.
> - I am using the access token in URL to get the data from server after validating the User.
> - While using the accesstoken it is displaying the data correctly with **http** request but not with **https** request.

Suppose, we have a URL whose data is http://example.com/Users/Accesstoken(length:350).

So this url will work but if we are replacing the **http** with **https** then it is showing the error

```
Bad Request - Invalid URL

HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.
```

What I have tried are as follows:

I have tried using the maxURLlength in IIS to get the data, But it has not worked.

I have tried maxquerystring in IIS, this also not worked.

I have tried the port which I have used in nodejs application, this does work in http but not in https.

Now on increasing the limit of Maximum URL length under Feature Settings inside the IIS configuration request filtering settings also it is showing the ssl not secured.


Please help me out in knowing how this can be solved as I need the node js application for calling api and then I need those api's to be used in different applications like asp.net, reactjs, android, ios, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The request URL is invalid in IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447698/the-request-url-is-invalid-in-iis-7)

Comment: No @Molda it is not correct as it has to be related to NodeJS application which is creating the problem with the IIS server. The domain was showing the correct SSL but the JWT access token from Nodejs was not allowing the application with SSL. So I have just removed the SSL from IIS Manager and added into the node js application, which has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question. It is the issue of SSL not linked with my nodejs application. So in this situation, I have used the SSL configuration while creating the HTTPS server and it has solved my issue. This is the link to the answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USrMdBF0zcg

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.